# how to obtain token info at response when calling post method api client adding parameters

Tags: c#, authentication, client, .net-6.0

With this I just can obtain 200 status code and reason Phrase is OK

```
public HttpResponseMessage Authenticate(string userName,string password)
{
    var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {userName=userName,password=password});
    var parameters = new RestApiClientMethodParameter
    {
        AdditionalUri = "authenticate" , Body = jsonString
    };
    var result = _restApiClient.Post(parameters);
    return result;
}
```

This is Post method of _restApiClient :

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(RestApiClientMethodParameter parameter)
{
    try
    {
        var httpContent = new StringContent(parameter.Body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return _client.PostAsync(parameter.AdditionalUri, httpContent).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

And my requestUri is also true when im debugging, any ideas?
Thanks

I tried to change method return type as my model, i expect to return a bearer token from that uri so i can say that im authenticated to that system

Comment: If your `result` contains a token, then it is should in the `HttpResponseMessage`'s content.  Like this => `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); `

Answer (score 0):

Hope my understanding about your question is right.

If you are just want to change the **return type** to a string which is a **token**, you can use `ReadAsStringAsync()`

```cs
//  Change method's return type
public async Task<string> Authenticate(string userName,string password)
{
    var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {userName=userName,password=password});
    var parameters = new RestApiClientMethodParameter
    {
        AdditionalUri = "authenticate" , Body = jsonString
    };

    var result = _restApiClient.Post(parameters);
    //  Use ReadAsStringAsync()
    return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Get result by `Result` property

```cs
string token = Authenticate("userName", "password").Result;
```

Comment: thank you so much, i think this answer works for me. now i get a token response in a result property.